# Creating and saving to file new png image in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, download, png, blob

I am trying to create new empty image with width and height and save it as png to file.

This is what i got:

```
var myImage = new Image(200, 200);
myImage.src = 'picture.png';


window.URL = window.webkitURL || window.URL;

var contentType = 'image/png';

var pngFile = new Blob([myImage], {type: contentType});

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = 'my.png';
a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(pngFile);
a.textContent = 'Download PNG';

a.dataset.downloadurl = [contentType, a.download, a.href].join(':');

document.body.appendChild(a);
```

I am trying to get transparent image with given width and height in `var myImage  new Image(200, 200)` as the output on the download.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Image element can only load an existing image. To create a new image you will have to use canvas:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

// set desired size of transparent image
canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;

// extract as new image (data-uri)
var url = canvas.toDataURL();
```

Now you can set `url` as `href` source for the a-link. You *can* specify a mime-type but without any it will always default to PNG.

You can also extract as blob using:

```
// note: this is a asynchronous call
canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
  var url = (URL || webkitURL).createObjectURL(blob);
  // use url here..
});
```

Just be aware of that IE does not support `toBlob()` and will need a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob#Polyfill), or you can use `navigator.msSaveBlob()` (IE does neither support the `download` attribute so this will kill two birds with one stone in the case of IE).

Answer (score 4):

Thank you K3N for replying to my question but i did not have time to wrap my head around your answer.

Your answer was just what i needed!

Here is what i got:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;

var url = canvas.toDataURL();

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = 'my.png';
a.href = url;
a.textContent = 'Download PNG';



document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

canvas.width = 200;
canvas.height = 200;

var url = canvas.toDataURL();

var a = document.createElement('a');
a.download = 'my.png';
a.href = url;
a.textContent = 'Download PNG';



document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).