# HTML download file button only saving as HTML document

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am trying to add a "download file" button to my gatsby site like so:

```
<a
    href="../../images/project-logos/placeholder-company-logo.png"
    download="test"
    className="responsive-square project-logo"
>
    <img
        src={
            props.logo ??
            require("../../images/project-logos/placeholder-company-logo.png")
        }
        alt="Company Logo"
        className="logo-img"
    />
</a>
```

That image 100% exists in that location because it is being displayed by the `<img>` tag right below but when I click it it opens the download menu and only allows me to Save as type: HTML document. How do I get it to recognize that it's a png?

Comment: This whole `require()` business on something like a `src` attribute is suspicious to me.  I don't use React, but wouldn't `require()` be for loading a module?  Why wouldn't you just output the string literal?  What HTML is actually ending up in the DOM?  What does your HTTP request/response look like?

Comment: Can't you just do `(props.logo ?? <img ... />)`?

Comment: @J.Ko no because i want to use props.logo as the src url but if that's undefined then to use the placeholder-company-logo.png as the fallback

Answer (score 1):

I'm not terribly familiar with (what I assume is Gatsby specific) `require(...)` expressions as an `img` src attribute.

That being said, this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-snow-3krwi?file=/src/App.js) is hopefully enough of an example to solve your issue.

The basic functionality looks like this:

```js
  const [downloadUrl, setDownloadUrl] = useState(null);
  const downloadOnClick = () => {
    // Create a canvas element to "export" the image from
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

    // set desired size of transparent image
    canvas.width = 200;
    canvas.height = 200;

    // extract as new image (data-uri)
    const url = canvas.toDataURL();
    setDownloadUrl(url);
  };

  ...
  
  <a
    onClick={() => downloadOnClick()}
    href={downloadUrl ?? "https://via.placeholder.com/200"}
    download="test"
    className="responsive-square project-logo"
  >
```

For further reading (and what this answer was based on) check out this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932645/creating-and-saving-to-file-new-png-image-in-javascript).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Accessing directly to the DOM via `document.` is a bad practice that should be avoided since you are creating a virtual DOM in React and Gatsby. `require` is a JavaScript function, not Gatsby specific.

Answer (score 0):

When you handle images sources in React (and Gatsby due to webpack's configuration) you should import them as a component and that imported component should be the source, like:

```
// other imports
import MyImage from "../../images/project-logos/placeholder-company-logo.png"

const MyComponent = () =>{

return <a
    href="../../images/project-logos/placeholder-company-logo.png"
    download="test"
    className="responsive-square project-logo"
>
    <img src={props.logo && MyImage}
        alt="Company Logo"
        className="logo-img"
    />
</a> 
}
```

In addition, your logical operator should be `&&` in this case, since it's a boolean condition. You want to print `props.logo` if exists.

More information about [importing images and assets with Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/importing-assets-into-files/#importing-assets-with-webpack).

Comment: Thanks for the response, going to try it out soon! And as for the && operator, I don't believe I want that functionality unless I'm misunderstanding it. I want it to display the props.logo url unless that is undefined then display the MyImage. If I use && and the props.logo is undefined won't it just return false and not have any src then?

Comment: Just tried importing the image as a component and am still getting the same result of only allowing the save as to be an HTML document :( I'll post the issue to Gatsby to see what they have to say about it